# Getting the Assembly classes using Mono in C++

Tags: c#, c++, mono, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a Game Engine and I'm implementing a c# scripting system using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/).

I'm loading the assembly info without problem until I need to create a [MonoClass](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=xhtml%3Adeploy%2Fmono-api-class.html).
To create a MonoClass I need the MonoImage, Namespace and Class Name:

```
MonoClass* mono_class_from_name (MonoImage *image, const char* name_space, const char *name)
```

But how can I know the Namespace and Name if I haven't created the dll? (Because is a compiled script made by a user using the engine).

Should I use other function to load the MonoClass? Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :P

```
std::list<MonoClass*> GetAssemblyClassList(MonoImage * image)
{
   std::list<MonoClass*> class_list;

   const MonoTableInfo* table_info = mono_image_get_table_info(image, MONO_TABLE_TYPEDEF);

   int rows = mono_table_info_get_rows(table_info);

   /* For each row, get some of its values */
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
   {
       MonoClass* _class = nullptr;
       uint32_t cols[MONO_TYPEDEF_SIZE];
       mono_metadata_decode_row(table_info, i, cols, MONO_TYPEDEF_SIZE);
       const char* name = mono_metadata_string_heap(image, cols[MONO_TYPEDEF_NAME]);
       const char* name_space = mono_metadata_string_heap(image, cols[MONO_TYPEDEF_NAMESPACE]);
       _class = mono_class_from_name(image, name_space, name);
       class_list.push_back(_class);
   }
   return class_list
}
```

If you want more info: [Metada access](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=xhtml%3Adeploy%2Fmono-api-metadata.html)